# Boost, exceptions, threads and asynchrony, how should I handle them?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, boost, boost-asio

I have many different threads (`boost::thread_pool`) to a `boost::asio::io_service`. The `io_service` will call a function which will trigger `async_read`, which will trigger yet another `async_read`, from which many functions might be called. This is all done within two classes: threads spawn from a `Server` class, and `async_read` is called from a `Client` class.

Provided I `throw` from those functions called by `async_read` (from the `Client` class), who will get to `catch` the exception? `Server`? if so, is there any way to disregard the error and resume regular execution?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read this part of the Boost.Asio [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers)?

**Summary**:
"If an exception is thrown from a handler, the exception is allowed to propagate through the throwing thread's invocation of run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one(). No other threads that are calling any of these functions are affected. **It is then the responsibility of the application to catch the exception**."

So it depends on where you have your `catch` statement.

**UPDATE**

The generic way that exceptions work is that upon an error the function creating the error will `throw` an exception. Any calling function will have to `try` the worker function it calls, and `catch` the exception to resolve the error. Optionally, you could re-throw the caught exception (or any other exception) to any calling functions higher up the chain.

```
void some_function()
{
    // do some work

    if (error_occurred) 
        // don't know context, so pass the buck to calling function
        throw std::exception;
}

void some_calling_function()
{
    try {
        some_function(); // could throw
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        // do some error handling depending in context
    }
    // code will resume here
}
```

Comment: Please add a summary of what can be found at this link, or an example of code that solves the OP's issue: if I save this page and read it offline, your answer is not worth anything :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. OK with the summary, but without code from the OP, how can I provide code that solves his problem?

Comment: Well it's a general guideline, thus the *or* :) +1 for taking the time to update your answer.

Comment: do you have any info on ways to recover from exceptions and resume execution?

Comment: @JulianBayardoSpadafora See my updated answer and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/exception/